# Maas Web Interface not reachable after new installation!

Tags: maas

I have the following problem. I have 2 testservers and I want to configure one of them as maas server and the other as node. I downloaded the latest 12.10 and used the maas option during the installation process. After rebooting the apache2 is running but opening maas results in the following:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Machine is an old HP DL180 G3 that ran smoothly under 12.04.2 LTS! The following error appears in var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=1929): Target WSGI script '/usr/share/maas/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=1929): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/maas/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/share/maas/wsgi.py", line 30, in <module>
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     start_up()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/start_up.py", line 59, in start_up
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     inner_start_up()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/start_up.py", line 81, in inner_start_up
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     setup_maas_avahi_service()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/maasavahi.py", line 52, in setup_maas_avahi_service
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     service.publish()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/maasavahi.py", line 44, in publish
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     self.service.publish()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/zeroconfservice.py", line 46, in publish
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     bus.get_object(avahi.DBUS_NAME, avahi.DBUS_PATH_SERVER),
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     'su', (bus_name, flags)))
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error]     message, timeout)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:01 2013] [error] DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Activation of org.freedesktop.Avahi timed out
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121] mod_wsgi (pid=1928): Target WSGI script '/usr/share/maas/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121] mod_wsgi (pid=1928): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/maas/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/share/maas/wsgi.py", line 30, in <module>
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     start_up()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/start_up.py", line 59, in start_up
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     inner_start_up()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/start_up.py", line 81, in inner_start_up
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     setup_maas_avahi_service()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/maasavahi.py", line 52, in setup_maas_avahi_service
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     service.publish()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/maasavahi.py", line 44, in publish
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     self.service.publish()
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/zeroconfservice.py", line 46, in publish
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     bus.get_object(avahi.DBUS_NAME, avahi.DBUS_PATH_SERVER),
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 175, in activate_name_owner
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     's', (bus_name,), **keywords)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121]     message, timeout)
[Thu Apr 04 17:06:05 2013] [error] [client 10.6.22.121] DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.Avahi': no such name
```

I have not any clue what is going on here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is something wrong with the avahi service, can you try running:
$ sudo service avahi-daemon restart
And see if this fixes the problem?

Comment: i got the web interface but now the link between regional controller and the region worker process seems to be broken.

Comment: it took a while but maas now noticed that the controller has no images. i am downloading them at the moment. any ideas why the avahi daemon was not activated in the first place?